Does GNATCOLL.traces exist?
Whenever I look up logging in Ada, one of the recommendations is GNATCOLL.Traces.  I can see the documentation for it but there is no code.
If I try something like
with GNATCOLL.Traces;

I get an error.  If I tell alr
alr with gnatcoll_traces

It says gnatcoll.traces does not exist.  I have found a logging system that works in utilada (Util.Log.Loggers) but I keep wondering

Where is the code for GNATCOLL.Traces.  On Linux, what do I need to install to use it?
It must have existed at one time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25404890/2041317 talks about colourizing it
Has it been superseded by something else


See also gnatcoll-core: Traces: Logging information.

I've seen that - what's missing is here is a working example.  There seems to be a lot of guesswork to figure out what to do.

It should be part of GNATCOLL Core packages, so just do a
alr with gnatcoll


This is not an answer: just a simple example of usage which can be used as a starting point.  Everything is logged to the screen.  A configuration file should be passed to Parse_Config_File to invoke other features
with GNATCOLL.Traces; use GNATCOLL.Traces;

procedure main is
   loginfo: constant Trace_Handle := Create("Info");
   logdebug1: constant Trace_Handle := Create("debug1");
   logdebug2: constant Trace_Handle := Create("debug2");

   procedure level2 is
   begin
      -- Change indentation of logging
      Increase_Indent(logdebug2);
      Trace(logdebug2, "Nesting is for birds");
      Trace(logdebug2, "Nesting is for squirrels");
      Decrease_Indent(logdebug2);
   end level2;

   procedure level1 is
   begin
      -- Increase and decrease only work when handle is active
      Increase_Indent(logdebug1);
      Trace(logdebug1, "Up a level or down a level");
      level2;
      Decrease_Indent(logdebug1);
   end level1;

begin
   -- This is needed whether or not there is a config file
   -- If there is a config file, pass it in as a parameter
   -- By default, everything will log to the screen 
   Parse_Config_File;

   -- This will not appear - loginfo not active
   Trace(loginfo, "Useless trace");

   -- Enable tracing.
   Set_Active(loginfo, true);
   Set_Active(logdebug1, true);
   Set_Active(logdebug2, true);

   Trace(loginfo, "Now you should see something");

   for ii in 1..5 loop
      level1;
   end loop;

   -- Only trace debug2
   Trace(loginfo, "Switch off debug1");
   Set_Active(logdebug1, False);
   level1;

   -- Only trace debug1
   Trace(loginfo, "Switch on debug1, switch off debug2");
   Set_Active(logdebug1, True);
   Set_Active(logdebug2, False);
   level1;
   Trace(loginfo, "End of test");
end main;

If using alr
alr with gnatcoll
alr run

Output
[INFO] Now you should see something
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
      [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
[INFO] Switch off debug1
   [DEBUG2] Nesting is for birds
   [DEBUG2] Nesting is for squirrels
[INFO] Switch on debug1, switch off debug2
   [DEBUG1] Up a level or down a level
[INFO] End of test

